# How to find out current installed applications in android using GPS

Tags: android, gps

Is there anyway to find out the current installed application in android using GPS ?

Are there any APIs in android available to find out this information ?

Comment: wow thats amazing gps can now find installed apps too...

Comment: maybe you can check how App Ops is doing it (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.findsdk.apppermission&hl=de). They give you a list of apps who use GPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get application names with specific permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026257/get-application-names-with-specific-permission)

Comment: longilong - Yes I know many applications do that but i was wanted to know how it can be done programatically...

Comment: Thanks Steve - May be that will help me...I will try out