# enable clicking on list items android

Tags: android

my code displays installed apps having specific permissions in a listview. i want to open the settings where you can uninstall apps on each list item (app) .How do i do that?

**here is the snippet for opening app's settings**

```
packageName = "com.wagtailapp";
    try {
        // Open the specific App Info page:
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // Open the generic Apps page:
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**here is my activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          getInstalledApps(this);
          ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, results);

          ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

      private ArrayList<String> getInstalledApps(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
            if ((pk.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                Log.v("system app using internet = ", ""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
                continue;
            }

            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, pk.packageName) ||
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, pk.packageName))
                results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
        }

        Log.v("app using internet = ", results.toString());

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing with `listView.setOnItemClickListener();`

Comment: You need to create custom adapter and handle each item (view) click event in adapter's getView() method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851687/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      getInstalledApps(this);
      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, results);

      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   }


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) { 

    //your code here

}
```

Comment: your activity must implement 'OnItemClickListener'

Comment: The method onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                String packageName = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            try {
                // Open the specific App Info page:
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // Open the generic Apps page:
                Intent intent = new Intent(  android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

See if it works..

Comment: i implemented your code but it is not doing anything!

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code inside your onCreate() below listView.setAdapter(adapter);

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            String packageName = results.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: it opens the settings but immediately closes the settings and returns to the  app after half second.

Comment: Try this :

  int UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1; 

 startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: but where? im confused

Comment: its still the same, it opens but goes back after half second

Comment: Try this :

  int UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1; 
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
  startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);